# Build or download artifact using mvn

Tags: maven, npm, multi-module

I am using mvn for building React components using npm and webpack. This is done using the exec-maven-plugin.

These components are categorized into multiple child modules with a parent pom.
The output of the build process is a single artifact which includes components from all modules.

If there is a change in the module then it is to built, however if there is no change, then the already published module artifact needs to be pulled from the repository and included in the final artifact

There is a property file which the developer will update, this drives which modules need to be built.

The npm build is working as expected and I am able to build the final artifact using the maven-assembly-plugin, however I cant figure out a way to conditionally download an already published artifact or build it depending on the content of the property file.

I tried including all module artifacts as dependencies in my parent pom, but then I get an error stating dependencies.dependency is referencing itself.

Is there a way this can be achieved using mvn or I am completely offtrack here...